# WPF form cuts off everything below certain point

Tags: wpf

I just switched from WinForms to WPF today.
The problem I am facing right now is that **after a certain point, everything below gets cut off when I run the application** (in the designer I see everything).

The width is 1920 and the height is 1080. I am using `WindowState="Maximized"`, maybe that's why?

I want to create an application that is full-screen, but again - **after a certain point, everything below gets cut off when I run the application**
I just want to place them wherever, and for them to stay there, nothing special. So, maybe a "grid" is not needed?
Here's the XMAL code:

```
<Window x:Class="KodeOS.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KodeOS"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="KodeOS" Height="1080" Width="1920" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/kdroid_wallpaper1.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="KodeOS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe Print" FontSize="18.667" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="White"/>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="by Kamil" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe Print" Foreground="White"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="After here everything will be cut off" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,665,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255" RenderTransformOrigin="0.526,-0.807" Height="44"/>
    <Button x:Name="button_Copy" Content="I'm past the cut off zone" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,814,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179" RenderTransformOrigin="0.526,-0.807" Height="30"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: [This simple tutorial might help](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid/)

Comment: @nabulke I don't think adding a grid will help. Maybe you can try run it and see what the problem is? It also feels like the controls (buttons, label etc) positions maybe go down more than what I see in the designer?

Comment: You already _had_ a `Grid` in your example. The link explains how to use it correctly and why it produces wrong results now.

Comment: @nabulke I read it, but **all I want is to place my controls wherever. But, anything below a certain point is cut off when I run the application**? Maybe you can run it yourself and see?

Comment: WPF grid is like HTML tables+CSS; the conventional approach is stay away from fixed positions as much as possible. Instead relative sizes and positions should be preferred. In your case, your grid needs `Grid.RowDefinitions` and `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` elements first defined directly under grid node. And then you can use `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attributes in individual controllers like `label` to indicate their positioning. What you have done is put everything in a giant cell, which fails.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you don't align content in your grid by defining margins - you need to assign dedicated rows and columns to your Labels/Buttons/Whatever

For example, this piece of code

```
    <Grid Background="Gray">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label x:Name="label" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Content="KodeOS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe Print" FontSize="18.667" Foreground="White"/>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Content="by Kamil" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe Print" Foreground="White"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="After here everything will be cut off" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255" Margin="5" Height="44"/>
    <Button x:Name="button_Copy" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  Content="I'm past the cut off zone" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179"  Margin="5"  Height="30"/>

</Grid>
```

will result in a layout like that:
[image]

If you want to place your Objects manually, you can use the `Canvas` Container, you can place content there with `Canvas.Left' and`Canvas.Top`

For example:

```
    <Canvas Background="Gray">

    <Label x:Name="label"  Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="5" Content="KodeOS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe Print" FontSize="18.667" Foreground="White"/>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Canvas.Left="55" Canvas.Top="55" Content="by Kamil" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe Print" Foreground="White"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Canvas.Left="75" Canvas.Top="125" Content="After here everything will be cut off" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255" Margin="5" Height="44"/>
    <Button x:Name="button_Copy" Canvas.Left="125"  Canvas.Top="205" Content="I'm past the cut off zone" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179"  Margin="5"  Height="30"/>

</Canvas>
```

will turn out like that:
[image]

But generally I would not go for that, since you are not able to dynamically react on window-size changes

Comment: Thanks, but I am aiming to create it as a full-screen (maximized) WPF application. I do not need to position the controls in any special way, I just want to put them anywhere and for them to stay there. The height is 1080 and the width is 1920 (my screen resolution) and window state is maximized. In the designer, everything looks good but when I run it anything below some point is cut off, any help?

Comment: If only you will use the program, it is ok. But if other people will use it, their resolution could even be 800x600, and then they will not see even half of your window.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `Grid.Row` or `Grid.Column` being assigned to your controls such as the Label or Button. The grid system works a bit like Table Layout in Winform.

Usually in a Grid layout, you don't need to align elements with RenderTransformOrigin, Margns and Vertical/Horizontal Alignment and just setting up a proper grid layout should do.

You're putting your elements (button, label, etc.) in a Grid control. The way the Grid control works is that it arranges all the items based on a Column/Row value associated with those elements, e.g. put the Label in Row=0, Col=0, put the button in Row=0, Col=1). If you omit those values, the default Row/Column will be used which is zero.

This means, all the elements will essentially overlap, but you have managed to put them away from each other based on other spacing properties such as Margin/Padding, etc. which is not the way to go.

Comment: I don't really understand. Why do I need to assign `Grid.Row`/`Grid.Column` to my controls? And how? I haven't used a Table Layout in Winform before either.

Comment: @Kamdroid Clarified the answer, see if that helps. This is basic WPF layout system, if you're not familiar I'd advise reading a book (or using other resources at your disposal) as it is not exactly like WinForms.